# How to delete a nested object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, destroy

I created a blog that has articles and comments that are inside their article. I want to create an option so I can delete comments too but when I click the delete button the error says "Couldn't find Comment with 'id'=#id here"

```
resources :articles do
    resources :comments
end
```

View

```
<div>
<h4>Comment by <%= comment.author_name %></h4>
<p><%= comment.body %></p>
</div>
<p> <%= link_to "Delete Comment", article_comment_path(@comment.article_id, @comment.article.id), method: :delete %> </p>
```

Comments Controller

```
def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy

    redirect_to article_path(@comment.article)
end
```

Comment: will this help `<%= link_to "Delete Comment", article_comment_path(id: @comment.id, article_id: @comment.article.id), method: :delete %>`

Comment: @Gerep Your comment wouldn't work. Because route is nested. As per the route I see, you wouldn't get the helper `comment_path`

Comment: @ArupRakshit You are correct, I'll delete the comment

Comment: As you are only interested to destroy the comment, it is not need to show here the `form` you have.

Comment: @Athar You are right, but if you pass the object to the path helper method, Rails will extract the id from the object due to its _convention_ power. :D

Comment: @ArupRakshit you are absolutely correct. i was trying to be sure.:) but what you suggest is the best thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing the same article object with `... @comment.article_id, @comment.article.id ...`. Try this:

```
<%= link_to "Delete Comment", article_comment_path(@comment.article, @comment), method: :delete %>
```

**Edit**

I see now you're also trying to reference the `@comment` object after it's been destroyed.

```
def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy

    redirect_to article_path(@article)
end
```

Comment: That's not the problem. You shown it how OP can re write it much better that's it.

Comment: No, he's referencing the article object as if it were the comment object. The way I have in the answer is correct.

Comment: Actually it is, if the ID of the article is 199 and the comment ID is 4, it will try to delete the comment with ID 199 of article 199, which doesn't exist, hence the error: `Couldn't find Comment with 'id'=`.

Comment: You confused me now :)

Comment: @kjmagic13 you're right about what you're saying about the error, It's trying to delete a comment with the same ID as the article, I tried what ur answer but it's the same error again

Comment: @kushtrimh, see edit. Provide exact output of console if error persists. Thanks